# Unity: Build failure, unable to update the SDK package list on MAC

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I built an app 3 days ago and there were no errors, since yesterday, as soon as I tap build it gives me this error, I have searched a lot but can't find any solution for MAC - there are some ways to fix this on windows, but non on mac. I am using the default unity Android SDK, I also have other Android SDK but that too gives the same error. Console shows this

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema

    UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun() (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindow.cs:123)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun() (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindow.cs:123)
at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun() (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindow.cs:123)
```

here is a screenshot of My preferences settings
[image]